# Why does Console.ReadKey() block output of Console.WriteLine called in another thread?

Tags: .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, console-application

I have a very simple console app.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DoAsync();
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Here `DoAsync` starts set of task and returns not waiting for tasks' completition.
Each task writes to Console, but the ouptut is not shown before key is pressed.
When I use `Console.ReadLine` everything works fine.

So I'm curious about `ReadKey()` pecularities.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/471w8d85.aspx) for `Console.ReadKey()`:

> The ReadKey method waits, that is, blocks on the thread issuing the
>   ReadKey method, until a character or function key is pressed.

What it actually does is acquire a lock on `Console.InternalSyncObject`, which prevents further operations on the console.

The `Console.ReadLine()` method does not block the thread in this way.

Reading [this article](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/dorony/archive/2012/09/12/console-readkey-net-4-5-changes-may-deadlock-your-system.aspx) I'm guessing you have .NET 4.5 installed?

Comment: Many-many thanks, I was looking one level higher (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w19esh7k.aspx) And for the article too.